# Firebase Hosting "rewrites" to Access Next.js App on Google Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

We're using Firebase Hosting. We have a Next.js app, called "knowledge", deployed on Google Cloud Run in the same GCP project. We followed the instructions in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run). Our `firebase.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/knowledge{,/**}",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "knowledge",
          "region": "us-central1"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We want every request to "/knowledge{,/**}" for server-side rendering through our Next.js app on Cloud Run. When we open any of these pages, it loaded, but it does not load any of the static file, showing many errors like the following in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at webpack-df4cf1c8d23aa877.js:1:1)
framework-81da43a8dcd978d9.js:1
```

Our `next.config.js` is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrite() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/knowledge",
        destination: "/",
      },
    ];
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Static files will be under /_next/, so add '/path*'.

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrite() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/knowledge",
        destination: "/",
      },
      {
        source: "/knowledge/:path*",
        destination: "/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
  },
};
```